# Typesafe Activator Reative Maps java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: out-of-memory, typesafe, typesafe-activator

I downloaded and installed the latest version of Typesafe Activator, and created a new project with the Reactive Maps template, then tried to run it, but I get all kinds of java.lang.OutOfMemoryError exceptions in the log, and the UI is unresponsive.

No, I have not really started troubleshooting yet, but I would have expected these templates to be more robust and 'just work' -- is that a bad expectation?

I do not have a support contract, and could not find any way to ask for support; so is stackoverflow the best place to ask for help on these issues?

```
11:43:58.490 play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-7 E Weaving class problem. Original class has been returned. The error was caused because of: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError@6e29ae44
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.ExtensibleURLClassLoader.defineClass(ExtensibleURLClassLoader.java:63)
at org.aspectj.weaver.loadtime.WeavingURLClassLoader.defineClass(WeavingURLClassLoader.java:148)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.ExtensibleURLClassLoader.defineClass(ExtensibleURLClassLoader.java:97)
at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.ExtensibleURLClassLoader.findClass(ExtensibleURLClassLoader.java:52)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
at com.typesafe.sbt.echo.EchoPlayRun$$anonfun$createWeavingClassLoader$1$$anon$1.loadClass(EchoPlayRun.scala:50)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
at org.joda.time.DateTimeUtils.getChronology(DateTimeUtils.java:283)
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.selectChronology(DateTimeFormatter.java:940)
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.printTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:620)
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.printTo(DateTimeFormatter.java:497)
at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.print(DateTimeFormatter.java:599)
at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Assets.scala:142)
at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$10$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(Assets.scala:136)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Assets.scala:136)
at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Assets.scala:118)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Assets.scala:118)
at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Assets.scala:74)
at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1.apply(Assets.scala:74)
at controllers.AssetsBuilder$$anonfun$at$1.apply(Assets.scala:65)
at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:221)
at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anonfun$apply$10.apply(Action.scala:220)
at play.api.mvc.Action$.invokeBlock(Action.scala:357)
at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:309)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109)
at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$4$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:109)
11:44:00.224 application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3 E Weaving class problem. Original class has been returned. The error was caused because of:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError@3bdef2d
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, after rebooting my Windows system and running the the app again, this time it seems to work correctly. Must be another one of those environment/configuration mysteries as I did not change anything.